# Avoid symbolication of keys for ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, activeresource

I am using an ActiveResource model named "Setting" to connect to an external web service which delivers some response like the following example:

```
{"setting" => {"id" => 10, :details => {"10a" => 7, "10b" => 8}}}
```

The problem is, that ActiveResource tries to symbolize all keys in the `details` hash but this is not possible and raises a `NameError: wrong constant name 10a`. Is there any chance to prohibit the symbolication or even to avoid the transformation of `details` to a separate object?

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing with the details hash? Is it just being processed, or are you saving it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set your schema manually? I don't know if you can set nested attributes like this.

```
class Setting < ActiveResource::Base
   schema = {'setting' => {'id' => :integer, :details => {'10a' => :integer, '10b' => :integer}}}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the separate object is a HashWithIndifferentAccess?  Can you try calling `#deep_stringify_keys` on the details hash before using it?